# Initializing values of a Node in the constructor for a hash map C++

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, hashmap, valgrind

I'm supposed to create a Hash Map that stores a username and a password, which are stored as strings. This hash map is separately chained. When adding a value or searching for a value, I am supposed to use a hash function on a key that returns an integer which will then give me the index for the bucket I need to use a function on. If adding something I store it at the end of the list.

So the hash map (in my mind) would look like this:

```
Bucket | List
[0] -> nullptr
[1] -> (key1/value1) -> (key2/value2)
[2] -> (key3/value3)
```

Each key/value combo is technically a Node which has an unmodifiable structure in my header file, like this:

```
struct Node
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    Node* next;
};
```

Although my add and search function technically work, I want to correctly initialize my hash map in my constructor so that I am **not** doing a compare on an uninitialized value. This is how my constructor is now:

```
HashMap::HashMap()
    : hashTable{new Node*[initialBucketCount]}, amountOfBuckets{initialBucketCount}, sz{0}
{
    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfBuckets; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

The problem is, is that when I have to compare something, like in my add function, I get an error with valgrind that says I'm doing a conditional jump or move on uninitialised value(s). For example, doing this in add:

```
Node* current = hashTable[tableIndex];
if(current == nullptr)
    return false;
```

will say that `if(current == nullptr)` is referencing an uninitialized value.

How would I go about properly initializing values in the hashmap constructor? Especially if I want to do something in a function where I compare the beginning of the list to a value like nullptr so that I can determine where I need to put the next node in my list.

**Edit:** Here is everything condensed into one file.

```
/* HashMap.cpp */
namespace {
    unsigned int hashFunc(const std::string& key)
    {
        unsigned int hashValue = 0; // what we end up returning
        for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) { // iterate through string
            int letterIndex = key.at(i) - 96; // create an index for each ASCII char
            hashValue = hashValue * 27 + letterIndex;
        }
        return hashValue;
    } // end hashFunc
}
class HashMap
{
public:
    typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
    static constexpr unsigned int initialBucketCount = 10;

private:
    struct Node
    {
        std::string key;
        std::string value;
        Node* next;
    };
    HashFunction hasher;
    Node** hashTable;
    unsigned int amountOfBuckets;
    unsigned int sz;
public:
    HashMap()
    : hashTable{new Node*[initialBucketCount]}, amountOfBuckets{initialBucketCount}, sz{0}
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfBuckets; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = nullptr;
    }
    }
    HashMap(HashFunction hasher)
    : hasher{hashFunc}, hashTable{new Node*[initialBucketCount]()}, amountOfBuckets{initialBucketCount}, sz{0}
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfBuckets; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = nullptr;
    }
    }
    HashMap(const HashMap& hm)
    : hashTable{new Node*[hm.amountOfBuckets]}, amountOfBuckets{hm.amountOfBuckets}, sz{hm.sz}
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            hashTable[i] = hm.hashTable[i];
        } // end for
    }
    ~HashMap()
    {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < amountOfBuckets; i++) {
        Node* bucketNode = hashTable[i]; // store each hashtable list in a bucket node
        while(bucketNode != nullptr) {
            Node* deleteCurrent = bucketNode; // set current to the bucket node (head)
            bucketNode = bucketNode->next; // delete current is on the first node, update head to second node
            delete deleteCurrent;
        } // end while
    } // end for
    // once done, delete hash table
    delete[] hashTable;
    } // end destructor

    void add(const std::string& key, const std::string& value)
    {
    unsigned int hashedValue = hashFunc(key); // get hash value (unmodified by buckets)
    unsigned int tableIndex = getTableIndex(hashedValue); // get the table index
    if(contains(key) == true) { // if key is already in the hashtable
        return; // exit program
    } else { // otherwise, key is not in the hash table
        Node* head = hashTable[tableIndex]; // head of the hash table, represents
        Node* current = head; // set current to first node
        if(current == nullptr) { // no nodes yet
            // nothing in bucket
            current = new Node(); // construct single node
            current->key = key; // set key (username)
            current->value = value; // set value (password)
            current->next = head; // add value to head of list
            hashTable[tableIndex] = current; // update current to point to front of list
            return; // exit
        } else {
            while(current->next != nullptr) {
                current = current->next; // advance to next node
            } // end while
            // currently at node we want to insert key/value at
            current = new Node();
            current->key = key; // set key(username)
            current->value = value; // set value (pw)
            current->next = nullptr; // set next to point to nullptr
        } // end inner if-else (creates node)
    } // end outer if-else
    } // end add
    bool contains(const std::string& key) const
    {
    unsigned int hashedValue = hashFunc(key); // hash the key given to get an index
    unsigned int tableIndex = getTableIndex(hashedValue); // get the table index
    Node* current = hashTable[tableIndex];
    if(current == nullptr) { // if there are no nodes at given index
        return false;
    } else { // there are some nodes in the hash table
        while(current != nullptr && current->key != key) {
            current = current->next;
        } // end while
        if(current == nullptr) { // we reached the end of our linked list
            return false; // couldn't find a value
        } else { // we found the key provided
            return true;
        }
    } // end if-else
    }
    std::string value(const std::string& key) const
    {
        if(contains(key) == true) { // found match
            unsigned int hashedValue = hashFunc(key); // hash the key given to get an index
            unsigned int tableIndex = getTableIndex(hashedValue); // get the table index
            Node* current = hashTable[tableIndex];
            while(current != nullptr && current->key != key) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            return current->value; // return value after traversal
        } else {
            return ""; // no match, return empty string
        }
    }
}; // end class
/* main.cpp */

int main()
{
    // initialize test
    HashMap test1;
    std::cout << "TEST 1 HASHMAP OBJECT CREATED" << std::endl;
    // add some values
    std::string key1 = "Alex";
    std::string value1 = "password1";
    std::string key2 = "Danielle";
    std::string value2 = "password2";
    std::cout << "strings have been created" << std::endl;
    // add to hash map
    test1.add(key1, value1);
    test1.add(key2, value2);
    std::cout << "Keys and values have been added to hash map" << std::endl;
    // does key1 contain the word "hi"? no, should return false (0)
    std::cout << "Hash map contains word hi?: " << test1.contains("hi") << std::endl;
    // does key2 contain word "Danielle"? yes, should return true (1)
    std::cout << "Hash map contains word Danielle?: " << test1.contains("Danielle") << std::endl;
    // copy constructor test
    HashMap test2{test1};
    test2.add("Chicken", "lizard1");
    std::cout << "Password for user Chicken: " << test2.value("Chicken") << std::endl;
    HashMap test3 = test2;
    // pw should stay lizard1 (doesn't work rn)
    std::cout << "Password for user Chicken after copy: " << test3.value("Chicken") << std::endl;
    // check to see if we get value
    std::cout << "Password for user " << key1 << ": " << test1.value(key1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Password for user " << key2 << ": " << test1.value(key2) << std::endl;
    // should return empty string
    std::cout << "Test of incorrect password for invalid user INVALID: " << test1.value("lol") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your initialization looks OK. It is hard to tell what the problem with valgrind is without seeing an MCVE. (Aside, I hope you won't really store passwords, or write your own hashmap, in a real-world program).

Comment: @n.m. Is the MCVE just whatever valgrind outputs? In that case I can add an edit going through it. On a side note, this is just a class assignment :)

Comment: No MCVE is complete buildable source code that reproduces the problem. Something I can copy, paste, compile, run and see the error you are seeing, without jumping through hoops.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry about that. Here is the full code that I am working with.
http://www.mediafire.com/view/40p875a4k3kbq22/HashMapTest

Comment: Do not post links to code archives, post code as a single file inline in the text of the question. This means you need to work to reduce the code to a single file of reasonable size.

Comment: I have not emphasized the "one file" bit enough. Here's it again. **One file** please.

Answer (score 0):

You write in a comment in your default ctor

```
// initialize each node to nullptr from the array of buckets to nullptr
```

And then proceed to do something else entirely. And that other thing is totally wrong. You initialize all node ptrs to point to the same node. Which means that at destruction you will delete the same node many times, and crash and burn.

Also fix that warning.

*Update* The new version of the code, after fixing obvious errors, has a broken copy constructor and no assignment operator.

```
hashTable[i] = hm.hashTable[i];
```

will make two hash tables share data elements. You want copying, not sharing. And you want to copy all the buckets, not `sz` buckets (you never update `sz` but that's another issue).

Comment: So how would I end up initializing the list at each bucket index? I had originally set hashTable[i] = nullptr, which I originally thought worked, but it really didn't. Would I have to create some sort of initial node on each iteration of the for loop and set that equal to the hashTable at index i?

Comment: Please make sure code you are posting compiles. You are missing include directives, andd there is no `getTableIndex` defined anywhere. Before posting a blob of code, compile it yourself and verify that you are getting the expected output. Please also try to not change the code mid-game such that it invalidates answers. Your current version, after fixing obvious errors, has a broken copy constructor and no assignment operator.